# Facebook V2.3 to getFriends list

Tags: php

Is there any solution to get complete Facebook friends list without asking for APP permission?

Submitted for review many times but Facebook is not approving.

We need it in one of our applications.

Comment: Why would Facebook allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Facebook API documentation, you can't

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends

Comment: Yes according to Facebook document there is no direct way to access the friends list. But there should be some way I think as many applications are running on this logic only, so they might be stopped working. Please share if any one is getting same problam